# Combining checkout.session.completed and invoice.payment_succeeded

Tags: stripe-payments

My basic setup is creating a session and completing a payment with a Stripe webhook sent when checkout.session.complete is true.

But to be able to update the current_period_end in my database, I have to use a webhook for when invoice.payment_succeeded is true.

This works together, but, I have a problem!

**Problem:** When a user subscribes for the first time, Stripe sends a webhook of both checkout.session.complete and invoice.payment_succeeded.

I want to receive only the checkout.session.complete when a user first subscribes, so is it possible to prevent the invoice.payment_succeeded from being sent the first time / when checkout.session.complete is sent?

Answer (score 1):

The `invoice` object has the attribute [billing_reason](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason). If the `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook event is triggered by creating a new subscription, the value of `billing_reason` will be "subscription_create".

Answer (score 0):

Set "meta_data" to the type of cusotmer depending on customer found on stripe or not thorugh api search. This will help to compare when you receive the payment.